# How can I edge concrete without an edge trowel?

Tags: concrete, tools, floor

How can I make a concrete floor (also using dry shake color hardener) with a proper edge, without using an [edge trowel](http://ag.csuchico.edu/AgMech/ImagePages/images/Edge%20Trowel.jpg)?

In Brazil I cannot find an edge trowel anywhere, so I would like to know if there is some alternative to it. Maybe bending the edge of a regular trowel (how to make it rounded though?), or using some other tool or method.

Normally there isn't much care about the edging here and it usually ends up flush with the wall or the other floor. Even the spaces for dilation are usually made afterwards with circular saw and a concrete cutting disc.

Comment: Do they still sell cheap rectangular metal gas (petrol, benzin) cans in Brazil, or big tins of Spam?  Both have the required curve at the end of a flat surface. Cut to size w tin snips, and attach a handle.

Comment: We do have cans with curved corners, they seem to be a bit too flimsy for this, but I will give it a try, In any case it is better than nothing.

Comment: Any automotive body shops around? Using a dolly and body hammer on a piece of flat steel or thicker aluminum sheet to form a rounded bend along one edge of a rectangle was a really common skill in the old days of creating replacement parts from scratch.